# Redshift external table from parquet file showing null values for string data type

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, parquet, pyarrow, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am creating an external table in Redshift, pointing at a Parquet file stored in S3. The parquet file is created with pyarrow. When I SELECT * the external table defined below the "timestamp" works but the "anonymous_id" (VARCHAR) is null. The same applies to any VARCHAR.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE
propensity_identify  
(anonymous_id VARCHAR(max),
 timestamp timestamp without time zone)
PARTITIONED BY (loaded_at timestamp)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://bucket/key'
TABLE PROPERTIES ('compression'='none', 'serialization.null.format'='')
```

The parquet schema is:

```
anonymousId: BYTE_ARRAY UTF8
timestamp: INT96
```

Any idea why that happens? STL_S3CLIENT_ERROR says:

```
S3ServiceException:HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden,Status 403
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: seems like when you have defined the `external schema` and IAM role specified at that time is incorrect or having no access.

Comment: Thanks @RedBoy, if that was the case I would not see any output. The timestamps appear to be correct while string is null

Comment: Are you sure the 403 in `stl_s3client_error` relates to that query? You can run your Spectrum query, then run `SELECT pg_last_query_id();` to find the query id, then look for that query id in the stl_ table.